# Is there a way to stop auto horizontal scrolling with word wrap disabled

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome 80 the devtools now seems to auto horizontal scroll, to the right, to the content in tree views, but not back to the left when navigating back to a parent node. This makes the **Elements** tab very difficult to use with *Word Wrap* disabled. I mainly use the **Elements** tab to highlight elements to view the styles or to see the the parent/child relationship of the nodes. Word wrap makes it hard to view the hierarchy, because a node with many attributes will just take up all the horizontal space when it wraps. Now every time I click a child element I have to manually scroll back to the left to see the start of the parent nodes.

I don't know if this would be considered a bug, because I could see scrolling to the content useful in some places, but it has made the **Elements** tab difficult to use. Does there happen to be a way to toggle this feature to make horizontal scrolling manual only, because if I need to scroll I will just use the scrollbar myself.

Update:
This is fixed on canary now. The commits that broke and fixed it are referenced from the issue I reported here: https://crbug.com/1050868

Comment: I'd say autoscroll is bad UX in the majority of cases because web developers need to see the encompassing context which is more than just one parent node, and often it's important to see the entire hierarchy path. Consider suggesting the idea on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I am also annoyed by this behavior. Did you happen to find a fix?

Comment: @s3v3n I did not find a fix that could work on stable. The fix is on canary. I think it happens when the `focus()` function is called on partially off screen elements. There may be a way to clip or limit the width to avoid the elements from being off screen, but I just switched to the canary build of Google Chrome, and Edge, and it is fine for me there.

Comment: Great to hear that a fix is on its way! Thank you!